# Accessing commit history from github via terminal?

Tags: macos, git, github, terminal, github-api

Need some quick help. Novice terminal user here. Trying to use these instructions: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#commit-activity to get commit history for a specific user.

However, I don't know what to do with this:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors
```

When I replace the owner and repo with the specific names i'm using, nothing happens because I get this error in my terminal:

```
-bash: GET: command not found
```

This is a very time sensitive issue, help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to make an HTTP GET request using curl.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: "curl https://api.github.com/repos/:(u/n here)/:(repository here)/stats/contributors"

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Says it's not found and gives a link to their developer github page.

Comment: Finally got it. Typo, was including the ":"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this [curl tutorial using GitHub's API](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960) to see how you would translate

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors
```

As you notice [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985976/accessing-commit-history-from-github-via-terminal#comment40693060_25985976), the ":" shouldn't be included.

```
curl --include https://api.github.com/users/caspyin
```

> Pass user credential to basic auth to access protected resources like a users starred gists, or private info associated with their profile

```
curl --user "caspyin:PASSWD" https://api.github.com/gists/starred
curl --user "caspyin:PASSWD" https://api.github.com/users/caspyin
```

> Passing just the username without the colon (`:`) will cause you to be prompted for your account password.
>   This avoids having your password in your command line history

```
curl --user "caspyin" https://api.github.com/users/caspyin
```

---

In your case, replacing `<owner>` and `<reponame>` by the right owner and repo names:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<reponame>/stats/contributors
```